# Recording microphone jack in Ubuntu

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, microphone

Greetings, I'm attempting to record Live TV from a TV capture card to FLV files with FFmpeg. When I first started on this project 2 weeks ago I was expecting something quit simple. Yet, so far I've gotten nowhere.

If I do the following

```
ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/dsp1 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 test.flv
```

I video, but no audio.

If I start an instance of VLC, XawTV or anything which effectively 'turns on' my TV tuner (and therefore opens the audio channel from my mic jack), then I can record the audio using.

```
ffmpeg -f oss -i hw:0,0 test.mp3
```

Well, the problem is that I want both audio in video in a single .flv, not split up into 2 files which start and stop at different times.

Somehow, starting an instance of VLC, or XawTV is "opening" the input from the microphone and causing it's data to be available to other interfaces. Before "opening" the input, if I have a Pulse Audio Volume Control open and look at inputs I'll see basically nothing. But, as soon as I do an action which 'opens' the input then suddenly there is data there. Regarding video, 'opening' the input is not required, any ffmpeg video4linux2 will record data.

The dilemma is that so far I haven't found a way to 'open' the microphone input without simultaneously locking the video input (which opening VLC, Xawtv or the like does). If I had a means to open up that jack, then I could record an FLV file combining the two sources. Either that or I need a way to simply record the input directly from the microphone jack, but unfortunately that request on SuperUser got crickets =p ([TV tuner audio plays over speakers but can't record it](https://superuser.com/questions/178240/tv-tuner-audio-plays-over-speakers-but-cant-record-it)).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.